# ¿Cómo hacer una cadena alternada de mayúsculas y minúsculas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, bucle-for

```py
 cadenadeprueba="Ejemplo de frase con muchos caracteres"

for i in cadenadeprueba:
    seleccionPalabra=cadenadeprueba.find(i)
    if seleccionPalabra//2==0:
       i.upper()
print(cadenadeprueba)
```

quiero hacer un string que tenga la mayuscula y minúscula alterada,pero no se bien como hacerlo, he intentado esto y muchos otras formas, pero comunmente no cambia ninguna letra o da error como en este caso, alguien puede ayudarme?

Comment: `"".join(f(c) for f,c in zip(itertools.cycle([str.upper, str.lower]), cadenadeprueba))`  ;-) (pregunta si te interesa)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

La idea creo que la tienes: modificar los caracteres pares a mayúscula, pero tienes algunos problemas en tu código:

- El método `find()`, al menos como lo estás llamado, esta retornando siempre la primer ocurrencia del caracter por el cual estas iterando
- Por otro lado para averiguar si un caracter se encuentra en una posición par, estas usando una operación equivocada `//` es básicamente "floored quotient of x and y", en realidad necesitas el módulo `%`
- Por último `i.upper()` solo pone en mayúscula el caracter `i` no hace ninguna modificación sobre la cadena original.

La forma más sencilla y similar a lo que has intentado, es hacer algo así:

```
cadenadeprueba="Ejemplo de frase con muchos caracteres"

lista_chars = list(cadenadeprueba)
for i, char in enumerate(lista_chars):
  if i % 2 == 1:
    lista_chars[i] = char.upper()

nueva_cadenadeprueba = "".join(lista_chars)
```

Básicamente:

- Descomponemos `cadenadeprueba` en una lista de caracteres
- iteramos sobre cada caracter y al mismo tiempo obtenemos el índice del mismo dentro de la lista
- Si el índice es par `if i % 2 == 1` pasamos el caracter a mayúscula y reemplazamos el mismo de la lista
- Por último `nueva_cadenadeprueba = "".join(lista_chars)` juntamos todos los caracteres en una nueva cadena.
- Técnicamente hablando deberíamos hacer mejor algo así, para garantizar mayúsculas y minúsculas:

  ```
  if i % 2 == 1:
     lista_chars[i] = char.upper()
  else:
     lista_chars[i] = char.lower()
  ```

Answer (score 5):

Bueno al parecer ya te mostraron una forma de realizarlo, de todas formas pondre un ejemplo de otra forma:

```
cadenadeprueba="Ejemplo de frase con muchos caracteres"
cadenaSalida = ''
for i in range(0, len(cadenadeprueba)): # Iteramos segun la longitud de la cadena y utilizamos sus indices para acceder a cada caracter
    if (i % 2) == 0: # Verificamos si el indice es par para poder alternar la mayuscula y minuscula
        cadenaSalida += cadenadeprueba[i].upper() # Concatenamos las mayusculas en la cadena nueva
    else:
        cadenaSalida += cadenadeprueba[i].lower() # Concatenamos las minusculas en la cadena nueva
print(cadenaSalida)
```

Espero te sirva ;) Saludos.

Answer (score 4):

Dejo otros métodos algo diferentes a los ya aportados:

```
cadenadeprueba = "Ejemplo de frase con muchos caracteres"
```

**método 1**

```
metodo1 = ''.join(map(''.join, zip(cadenadeprueba[::2].upper(), cadenadeprueba[1::2].lower())))

print(metodo1)
```

**método 2**

```
metodo2 = len(cadenadeprueba) * ['']
metodo2[::2], metodo2[1::2] = cadenadeprueba[::2].upper(
), cadenadeprueba[1::2].lower()

print(''.join(metodo2))
```

**método 3**

```
from itertools import chain

print(''.join(chain(*zip(cadenadeprueba[::2].upper(), cadenadeprueba[1::2].lower()))))
```

Todos ellos devuelven:

```
EjEmPlO De fRaSe cOn mUcHoS CaRaCtErEs
```