# ¿como hacer una cadena que alterne una palabra en mayúscula y la siguiente en minúscula?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

necesito que al ingresar una cadena(frase) la primera palabra se ponga en mayúscula usando .upper y la siguiente palabra se ponga en minúscula usando .lower
tal que la frase quede así: FRASE alternada USANDO upper Y lower

Comment: ¿ Cómo has intentado resolverlo ?

Comment: vuelvo la cadena una lista con Split y después usar [0::2] haciendo que estas posiciones sean mayúsculas y [1::2] sean minúsculas o pues esa es como idea que tengo

Comment: Agrega el código del intento para que podamos corregirlo.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cómo hacer una cadena alternada de mayúsculas y minúsculas?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/313546/c%c3%b3mo-hacer-una-cadena-alternada-de-may%c3%basculas-y-min%c3%basculas)

Comment: es parecido solo que en vez de alternar cada letra debe alternar cada palabra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta función debe resolver tu problema, en ella se separan las palabras de la frase, y se itera sobre esta lista, aquellas que tengan índice par serán convertidas a "uppercase", las que no cumplan este criterio (índice impar) serán convertidas a "lowercase", al final se unifica el contenido de la lista nuevamente a un string.

```py
def alternate_upper_lower(string):
    words = string.split(" ")
    for i in range(len(words)):
        words[i] = words[i].upper() if i % 2 == 0 else words[i].lower()
    result = ' '.join([str(w) for w in words]) 
    return result
```

#### Ejemplo de uso

```py
phrase = input("Frase: ")
print(alternate_upper_lower(phrase))
```

Comment: para usar el código creo la variable string =input("ingrese frase") previamente y para que me de la frase al final doy print a result, pero la frase me queda igual no se que pueda estar pasando.

Comment: Edite la respuesta, agregue un ejemplo de uso

Comment: si así la uso y no me da, no se que estoy poniendo mal

Comment: Te invito a probar el código en este ambiente virtual https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_python_interpreter